# Save the coordinates position of a child

Tags: actionscript-3

I've got these functions :

```
private function onEmptySpaceClicked(e:MouseEvent):void{

    var myVar = e.currentTarget.name;

    if (e.currentTarget.name == "ES1"){
    trace("click on one");
    clickPuzzles.click1 = true;
    }
    if (e.currentTarget.name == "ES2"){
    trace("click on two");
    clickPuzzles.click2 = true;
    }

public function buildIt(e:MouseEvent):void{
if (clickPuzzles.click1){
        test.x = e.currentTarget.x;
    test.y = e.currentTarget.y;
    test.visible = true;
}
}
```

The builIt function is called by an other class.

Everything is working, but, is it possible to save e.currentTarget.x and y on the "onEmptySpaceClicked" function as a value ?

And then use it in my buildIt function ?

Like :

```
private function onEmptySpaceClicked(e:MouseEvent):void{

    var myVar = e.currentTarget.name;

    if (e.currentTarget.name == "ES1"){
    trace("click on one");
        clickPuzzles.click1 = true
    e.currentTarget.x && e.currentTarget.y = valueOfEs1
    }
    if (e.currentTarget.name == "ES2"){
    trace("click on two");
        clickPuzzles.click2 = true
    e.currentTarget.x && e.currentTarget.y = valueOfEs2
    }

public function buildIt(e:MouseEvent):void{
if (clickPuzzles.click1){
        test.position = valueOfEs1
    test.visible = true;
}
if (clickPuzzles.click2){
        test.position = valueOfEs2
    test.visible = true;
}
}
```

Thank you for your help

---

**EDIT**

Thank you for you advices.

Here's what I did :

```
private function onEmptySpaceClicked(e:MouseEvent):void{
            trace("click on it neww");
var myVar = e.currentTarget.name;
            var valXes1;
            var valYes1;
            var valXes2;
            var valYes2;
        if (e.currentTarget.name == "ES1"){
            trace("il faut écouter emplacement");
            clickPuzzles.click1 = true;
            valXes1 = e.currentTarget.x;
                        valYes1 = e.currentTarget.y;
            trace(valXes1);
                    }
            if (e.currentTarget.name == "ES2"){
            trace("il faut écouter emplacement VARI");
            trace("puzzle2 est vrai");
            clickPuzzles.click2 = true;
            valXes2 = e.currentTarget.x;
                        valYes2 = e.currentTarget.y;
            trace(valXes2);
                    }
}


        public function buildIt(e:MouseEvent):void{
            var valXes1;
            var valYes1;
            var valXes2;
            var valYes2;
if (clickPuzzles.click1){
        test.x = valXes1
        test.y = valYes1
        test.visible = true;
}
if (clickPuzzles.click2){
    trace("puzzle2 is called");
        test.x = valXes2
        test.y = valYes2
        test.visible = true;
}
}
```

The puzzles 2 or 1 are well called but it seems that valXes1 and valXes2 have exactly the same value (valYes1 and valYes2 too).

What did I do wrong ?

---

EDIT 2

Ok, so I've positioned emptyspace and emptyspace 2 like that :

```
            emptyspace .x = 0;
            emptyspace .y = 0;

                        emptyspace2.x = 50;
            emptyspace2.y = 50;

In the function onEmptySpaceClicked

if (e.currentTarget.name == "ES1"){
        trace("il faut écouter emplacement");
        clickPuzzles.click1 = true;
        valXes1 = e.currentTarget.x;
                valYes1 = e.currentTarget.y;
        trace(valXes1);
    }
if (e.currentTarget.name == "ES2"){
        trace("il faut écouter emplacement VARI");
        trace("puzzle2 est vrai");
        clickPuzzles.click2 = true;
        valXes2 = e.currentTarget.x;
                 valYes2 = e.currentTarget.y;
        trace(valXes2);

the trace(valXes1) is 0  and the trace(valXes2) is 50.
```

So it's working.

BUT, 
in this function :

```
public function buildIt(e:MouseEvent):void{
            var valXes1;
            var valYes1;
            var valXes2;
            var valYes2;
if (clickPuzzles.click1){
        test.x = valXes1
        test.y = valYes1
        test.visible = true;
}
if (clickPuzzles.click2){
    trace("puzzle2");
        test.x = valXes2
        test.y = valYes2
        test.visible = true;
}
}
```

the trace("puzzle2") is showing (good) but the test position is = at valYes1 and valXes1
(so the "test" movieclip is position at the wrong place)

Do you know what's wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes but instead of

```
 e.currentTarget.x && e.currentTarget.y = valueOfEs1
```

you would

```
valXes1 = e.currentTarget.x;
valYes1 = e.currentTarget.y;
```

or create a Point object and place x and y in a single Point

```
import flash.geom.Point;

es1Point = new Point();
es2Point = new Point();

es1Point.x = e.currentTarget.x;
es1Point.y = e.currentTarget.y;
etc etc ...
```

Comment: Thank you ! So no errors, but weirdly valXes1 and valXes 2 have the same value (0) ! Do you know why ? I'll edit my post in order to show you what I did.

Comment: Nope, the emptyspaces are called. emptyspace= new Emptyspace(stage, usableItems[0]); addChildAt(emptyspace, 0);

Comment: they would need to be on the stage or at least positioned before you can capture an x or y other than 0

Comment: Done ! So now the trace(valXes1); and trace(valXes2) are different (good), but there's still a problem. I eddit my post

Comment: Hmmm.. I've got this error when I click on an empty space : Property x not found on String and there is no default value.

Comment: Sorry, it is wrong to make it equal to myVar , that is a string (the name), not a referencee to the object. You need to pass valXes1 etc to buildIt. You seem to be declaring the variables again in buildit.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.. Do I have to put all the things in the onEmptySpaceClicked function into the buildIt function ? If so, I can't. I need that 2 functions and can't combine them.

Comment: (second question. Is it possible, with the configuration that I did, for the movieclip test to appear more than once ? (to be duplicate) ). Exemple : If clickPuzzles.click1 is true, test is visible at this point, and if clickPuzzles.click2 is true also, test is visible twice.

Comment: In answer to your first query, valXes1 etc need to be passed to buildIt or they need to be available globally for buildIt to retrieve once they've been set in the handler. Your second question doesn't make much sense..test is visible twice? you mean to create another copy of test? That's possible of course.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll see if I can pass valXes1 to be available globally. For the second question, yes I meant that. For the moment, I have duplicate the movieclip test, so I've got test2, test3..etc.

Comment: For the creation of another copy of test, do you want me to create a new post ?

Comment: yeah or 'automatically move this discussion to chat'? I don't have enough rep to do this at the moment, I've only just started using stackOverflow :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46760/discussion-between-user2421975-and-inkeydollardan)